# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with this string: `items[i].addClass('in');` ? it's killing me! I was tring different ways with `.each();` for example but it's still fail...

```
if(layer = 'aboutAuthor') {
    var items = $('.aboutAuthor .item');
    var K = 100; // Коэфициент.
    var t = K * (items.length + 1);
    for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(items[i]);
        setTimeout(function(){
            items[i].addClass('in');
        }, t);
        t += K;
    }
}
```

strange moment that **console.log()** displays each element in logs as expected, and normal. HELP!

Comment: Also `if(layer = 'aboutAuthor')` doesn't seem right and `items[i].addClass` should be something like `$(items[i]).addClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to not change the code too much, but I had assumed that you wanted to change the items in reverse.

```
if(layer === 'aboutAuthor') {
    var items = $('.aboutAuthor .item');
    var K = 100; // Коэфициент.
    var t = K * (items.length + 1);
    var i = items.length - 1;
    $(items.get().reverse()).each(function() {
        var item = $(this);
            console.log(item);
            setTimeout(function(){
                item.addClass('in');
            }, t);
            t += K;
        }
    });
}
```